# How to delete/change type of bus in the channel strip in Logic Pro X?

Tags: daw, mixing, logic-pro, effects, mixer

I'm playing around mixer atm, and I wanted to try to set pre/post fader send on one of my channels. Thing is that I'm able to add a bus, but I have no idea how to remove it, or change it's type. There are two buttons on the send - one to enable the send, and other (the one with two arrows up and down) which simply doesnt work...

Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong? Is Logic a stack of bugs? Every 10 pages of the manual I encounter some kind of problems :( Am I able to fix it somehow? Does it work for you guys? What can be the issue here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I was about to say sorry, and that I'm an idiot and "why I didnt come up on it earlier!", but no. The solution is not intuitive, because it is not consistent with how other up/down button works (on the insert for example)...

The answer is to **hold down a left mouse button on the up/down button** of the send until you'll get the contextual menu with options.